# insert values from other form

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, forms

At the moment I have a simple form that is getting his information for dropdown from a DB.

A fictive example:

```
<form name="mainForm" method="POST" action="mail.asp" onSubmit="return formvalidation(this);" >
  <table class="Tabel-BG" id="product" title="Product information">
  <tr><td>  
      Name: <INPUT type="text" name="Name" value="">
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>  
      Phone: <INPUT type="text" name="Phone" value="">
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>  
      Country: <INPUT type="text" name="Country" value="">
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>  
      Order Number: <INPUT type="text" name="Prod_OrderNumber" value="">
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Product Type :  
      <select name="Prod_Type" >
      <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
          <% do while not prod_prodType.EOF
                Response.write "<option value=""" & prod_prodType.fields("prod_type_code") & " " & rsprod_prodType.fields("prod_type_desc") & """>" &  prod_prodType.fields("prod_type_desc") & "  (" & prod_prodType.fields("prod_type_code") & ")</option>"
                prod_prodType.movenext
                loop
          %>
      </select>
  </td></tr>
  ...
  </table>
</form>
```

What I want to do is that the user is able to search on OrderNumber. And that,based on his choice, other fields will be filled in by an sql-query.

This would be the "workflow":

1. The user fill the Name-,Phone- and Country-field in
2. On order number he should get a pop-up, new window, ... (*)
3. In this new window he can search and select an order number (results comes from a DB). And on submit some field of the form will be filled in by values of an SQL query.
4. the user continues in the form the give more information in other fields
5. the user submits the form

(*) what is the best solution?

My problem is step 3. I need to keep the information that the user already give and I need to fill in other fields with the query result. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution that works for me...

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-value-from-child-popup-window-to-parent-page-window-using-JavaScript.aspx